# How to solve "Using temporary" (no "using filesort")

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

Now, I study about indexing to MySQL table and understanding result of explain.

I have this table(Because this is in Rails project, below code is `schema.rb`).

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "carrier",         limit: 1
  t.datetime "created_at"
end
```

`carrier` column is initials of their wireless carrier. This time,  for the sake of simplicity it can have three pattern char value:'a' or 'b' or 'c'.

I want to count record for each carrier in a certain period. I set composite index over crated_at and carrier and execute,

```
SELECT carrier, COUNT(carrier) 
FROM users 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2015-06-14' AND '2015-06-30' 
GROUP BY carrier
```

explain of this sql say `"Using where; Using index; Using filesort; Using temporary"`. According to MySQL referrence, MySQL automatically do sort when executing `group by`.By adding `order by null` to query, we can cancel the behavior. So I rewrite,

explain:
    SELECT carrier, COUNT(carrier) 
    FROM users 
    WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2015-06-14' AND '2015-06-30' 
    GROUP BY carrier 
    ORDER BY null

explain of this query is,

```
Using where; Using index; Using temporary
```

Although `Using filesort` disappeared, `Using temporary` is still. I thought that `Using temporary` is too for sorting, and disappeared with `Using filesort`, but not so.

Can I solve this `Using temporary`?. why this statement is outputted?

### Edit:

num of recode is about 100000, and I increase `max-heap-table-size` and `tmp-table-size` to 128MB (from default-16MB) .(my understanding about these variables is ambiguous...). Result of explain is no changed.

### Edit2:

I increase `innodb_sort_buffer_size` to 16MB(default 1MB).Result of explain is no changed.

Comment: See if increasing various memory settings fix the issue.

Comment: I add result of increase `max-heap-table-size` and `tmp-table-size` value. Is there other setting values I have to change?

Comment: I am not sure and just guessing. Give one last try by increasing `sort_buffer_size` (after which I am out of suggestions).

Comment: You do not solve this through configuration. Are necessary the right indexes, but they are not always possible. I'm not sure, can you try composite keys (created_at , carrier) or reversed